# Stuck in Processing Update for over a month

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

We try to get an update into the play store for over a month now (34 days). But we‘re basically stuck in „processing update“.

We tried to contact the Google Play Console support, they can‘t help us, they keep telling us „it takes time“. We also tried to contact them via Twitter, their they either said „it takes time“ and once „you were rejected, check the email for details“.

We never got an email, so we have no clue what‘s going on, we asked them to send the email again, no response.

Is there any way to get in touch with the review team to get this sorted, we‘re getting mad with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically nothing really helped here besides waiting, after 36 days both updates got approved. End of story.

Unless you know someone at the review team you won't have any luck.